# Disabling function that uses concept constrain if concept is not met

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

How can I make the following code compile?

I'm trying to check if BigStruct exist in a type, and enable `f` if it does.

```
#include <type_traits>
struct A {
    using BigStruct = int;
}; 

struct C {
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    void f(typename T::BigStruct t) requires requires {T::BigStruct;} {}
};

int main() {
  B<A> b1;
  B<C> b2;
}
```

Error I got:

```
<source>:11:24: error: no type named 'BigStruct' in 'C'
    void f(typename T::BigStruct t) requires requires {T::BigStruct;} {}
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:8: note: in instantiation of template class 'B<C>' requested here
  B<C> b2;
       ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:11:24: error: no type named 'BigStruct' in 'C'
    void f(typename T::BigStruct t) requires requires {T::BigStruct;} {}
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:8: note: in instantiation of template class 'B<C>' requested here
  B<C> b2;
       ^
1 error generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

[Here's a godbolt link for x86-64 clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/6oM3aGY6d).

Comment: is it on purpose that `B` is a class template? Or do you perhaps just want `f` to be a function template?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is on purpose that B is a class template.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: It's reasonable to assume that `B` contains other stuff. MCVEs are *minimal*, so they're not the original code.

Comment: @NicolBolas absolutely reasonable. Regarding concepts im a newbie, the question was pure curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concept checking for non-template functions happens after the function's signature has been generated. That means the parameter list has to exist. And therefore, it must be syntactically valid.

There's not much you can do in this circumstance, if you don't want to restrict the entire class, besides the old pre-C++20 strategy of [making the function itself a template](https://godbolt.org/z/hEjExGdK6):

```
template<typename U = T>
  requires requires {typename U::BigStruct;} 
void f(typename U::BigStruct t) {}
```

Comment: is there a benefit of the requires? I am asking because it seems to have the same efffect without https://godbolt.org/z/3nMne65Ee

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: It makes it more clear what the requirement is. SFINAE is kind of a hack.